# Display a the List of Child Records in the Inline VF Page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object associated with the standard Account object.
I want to display the list of all the child records of custom object in an inline VF page on Account detail page. How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There is an **[`<apex:relatedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm)** component you may find of use.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="Children__r" />
</apex:page>
```

You won't be able to control which records and fields show up with very much granularity, but it is a very low effort implementation and works well in many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list of children by using the relationship name in apex:pageBlockTable, apex:dataTable, apex:repeat, etc. Here's an example page that would iterate over a list of child records:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Children">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Children__r}" var="child">
            <apex:column value="{!child.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!child.Field1__c}" />
            <apex:column value="{!child.Field2__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```